# Show that a function is log supermodular

Tags: combinatorics, correlation

I have been struggling with the following

Let $X$ be finite and a poset $P = (X, \leq)$, and for any $A \subseteq X$ we can define the function $f_A$ on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ as follows
$$ f_A(Y) =  \#\{ I : \text{ $I$ is ideal of $P$ and $I \cap A = Y$ } \}$$
The problem is to show that $f_A$ is log supermodular for any $A$.

Log supermodular means that $f_A(Y_1)f_A(Y_2) \leq f_A(Y_1 \cap Y_2)f_A(Y_1 \cup Y_2)$.

Right now I have no idea how to begin attacking this, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm still a bit confused about the definition of $f_A$. Is it the number of ideals in P such that their intersection with A gives Y? Or somehow $f$ refers to the number of elements in I, assuming X is finite?

Comment: @SergioParreiras It is the first thing you said, the ideals whose intersection gives Y. And yes X is finite, I added that edit.

Comment: Why don't you pick X as the set of (m,n) with m,n positive integers less than some K and try to see how $f_A$ looks like for different A in X. Try to draw some pictures! How these ideals look like in $X\subset\mathbb{N}^2$?